# SQL Query, Count two columns based on same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have sql server databse with two tables, teams and games.  Each game has a predicted_winner column and a winner column. both columns reference the team table id field.   I want to query the database and get a count of how many games the team was predicted to win, and how many they actually won.  However based on my query it is only returning a count of the predicted_winner or the winner, whichever column I join the team table on.  how do I get accurate counts of both columns.

This is my incorrect query

```
SELECT teams.id, count(predicted_Winner), count(winner)
FROM teams left join games on teams.id=games.predicted_winner
GROUP BY teams.id
```

Comment: Provide us input/output, it would be nice to have a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) link

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Two columns in `games` table referencing back to One column in `Teams` table,

you will need to join this table twice back to `Teams` table, once for each column referencing to `teams` table.

```
SELECT t.id
     , count(g1.predicted_Winner) AS predicted_Winner_count
     , count(g2.winner)           AS winner_count
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN games g1 on t.id = g1.predicted_winner
LEFT JOIN games g2 on t.id = g2.winner
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the table twice, once for each column:

```
SELECT    teams.id, COUNT(pw.predicted_winner), COUNT(w.winner)
FROM      teams 
LEFT JOIN games pw ON teams.id = pw.predicted_winner
LEFT JOIN games w ON teams.id = w.winner
GROUP BY  teams.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with results(game_id, predicted_Winner, winner) as (
  select 1, 1, 2  union all 
  select 2, 1, 2  union all 
  select 3, 1, 1  union all 
  select 4, 4, 4  union all 
  select 5, 5, 6  union all 
  select 6, 6, 6  union all 
  select 7, 3, 5  
), teams(id) as (
  select 1  union all 
  select 2  union all
  select 3  union all 
  select 4  union all 
  select 5  union all 
  select 6 
)
SELECT t.id team_id
     , count(case when predicted_winner = t.id then 1 end)
     , count(case when predicted_winner = t.id and predicted_winner = winner then 1 end)
  from results res
  right join teams t on t.id = res.predicted_winner or t.id = winner
 group by t.id
 order by 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39354)